# Tizen xorg server

Tags: tizen, hardware-acceleration, xorg

We are trying to enable Graphics acceleration on our platform which has Tizen OS. The xorg-server version on Tizen is 1.13.x while the xorg-server with which we built the graphics modules has the version 1.16.x. We still don't have the drm driver because of which we are not able to test if the display is up. In the meantime, there is a small confusion on whether these graphics modules will work as is or we need to generate the modules with the version of xorg-server of the OS.

Thanks

Comment: modules as Linux's modules ? are you talking about hw drivers here ? if yes it depends on your selected hardware :)

Comment: not exactly about the hardware. It's about the conflict that may arise when there are two X servers of different versions being put on the platform. Anyway, I found that while generating the modules, we need to use the same X server version which is running on the OS